# Spring 3: @OneToOne unidirectional generate java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00918

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations, spring-annotations

I'm doing a project with Spring 3 + Hibernate. When I try to get an object what contains the object PoaUpa. I get **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00918** with this unidirectional join:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_ESCALA",referencedColumnName="ID_ESCALA",insertable=false,updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="ANO",referencedColumnName="ANO",insertable=false,updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="MES",referencedColumnName="MES",insertable=false,updatable=false)
})
private PoaUpa poaUpa;
```

Here is the query:

```
@Override
public Autorizacion getAutorizacionDeterminada(User u, Long ano,Long mes, Long escala) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Autorizacion a WHERE a.ano=:ano AND a.mes=:mes AND a.idEscala=:escala");
    q.setParameter("ano", ano);
    q.setParameter("mes", mes);
    q.setParameter("escala", escala);
    return (Autorizacion) q.getSingleResult();
}
```

And here the console output:

```
Hibernate: select * from ( select autorizaci0_.ano as ano0_, autorizaci0_.ID_ESCALA as ID2_0_, autorizaci0_.mes as mes0_, autorizaci0_.AUTORIZACION_HORAS_DIA_FIJIS as AUTORIZA4_0_, autorizaci0_.AUTORIZACION_HORAS_EVENT as AUTORIZA5_0_, autorizaci0_.AUTORIZACION_HORAS_FACTP as AUTORIZA6_0_, autorizaci0_.AUTORIZACION_HORAS_FIJIS as AUTORIZA7_0_, autorizaci0_.AUTORIZACION_HORAS_FIJOS as AUTORIZA8_0_, autorizaci0_.AUTORIZACION_HORAS_SEM_FACTP as AUTORIZA9_0_, autorizaci0_.AUTORIZACION_NAP as AUTORIZ10_0_, autorizaci0_.AUTORIZACION_NUM_PERS_EVENT as AUTORIZ11_0_, autorizaci0_.AUTORIZACION_OBSERVACIONES as AUTORIZ12_0_, autorizaci0_.PETICION_HORAS_DIA_FIJIS as PETICION13_0_, autorizaci0_.PETICION_HORAS_EVENT as PETICION14_0_, autorizaci0_.PETICION_HORAS_FACTP as PETICION15_0_, autorizaci0_.PETICION_HORAS_FIJIS as PETICION16_0_, autorizaci0_.PETICION_HORAS_FIJOS as PETICION17_0_, autorizaci0_.PETICION_HORAS_SEM_FACTP as PETICION18_0_, autorizaci0_.PETICION_NAP as PETICION19_0_, autorizaci0_.PETICION_NUM_PERS_EVENT as PETICION20_0_, autorizaci0_.PETICION_OBSERVACIONES as PETICION21_0_, autorizaci0_.ANO as ANO0_, autorizaci0_.MES as MES0_, autorizaci0_.REALIZACION_HORAS_DIA_FIJIS as REALIZA22_0_, autorizaci0_.REALIZACION_HORAS_EVENT as REALIZA23_0_, autorizaci0_.REALIZACION_HORAS_FACTP as REALIZA24_0_, autorizaci0_.REALIZACION_HORAS_FIJIS as REALIZA25_0_, autorizaci0_.REALIZACION_HORAS_FIJOS as REALIZA26_0_, autorizaci0_.REALIZACION_HORAS_SEM_FACTP as REALIZA27_0_, autorizaci0_.REALIZACION_NAP as REALIZA28_0_, autorizaci0_.REALIZACION_NUM_PERS_EVENT as REALIZA29_0_, autorizaci0_.REALIZACION_OBSERVACIONES as REALIZA30_0_ from TTR_AUTORIZACION autorizaci0_ where autorizaci0_.ano=? and autorizaci0_.mes=? and autorizaci0_.ID_ESCALA=? ) where rownum <= ?
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 918, SQLState: 42000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua

DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public es.iberia.tryp.model.entities.Autorizacion es.iberia.tryp.controllers.AdministracionController.getJSONAutorizacion(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,java.lang.Long)]: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua

DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public es.iberia.tryp.model.entities.Autorizacion es.iberia.tryp.controllers.AdministracionController.getJSONAutorizacion(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,java.lang.Long)]: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua

DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public es.iberia.tryp.model.entities.Autorizacion es.iberia.tryp.controllers.AdministracionController.getJSONAutorizacion(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,java.lang.Long)]: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua

DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua

    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1367)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:317)
    at es.iberia.tryp.model.entities.dao.impl.AutorizacionDAOImpl.getAutorizacionDeterminada(AutorizacionDAOImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy44.getAutorizacionDeterminada(Unknown Source)
    at es.iberia.tryp.services.impl.AdministracionServiceImpl.getAutorizacionDeterminada(AdministracionServiceImpl.java:233)
    at es.iberia.tryp.controllers.AdministracionController.getJSONAutorizacion(AdministracionController.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua

    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy56.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2254)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:284)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:799)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1037)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:839)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1132)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3316)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3361)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 61 more
05-jul-2012 10:51:08 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [appServlet] en el contexto con ruta [/tryp] lanzó la excepción [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua
] con causa raíz
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:799)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1037)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:839)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1132)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3316)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3361)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy56.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2254)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:284)
    at es.iberia.tryp.model.entities.dao.impl.AutorizacionDAOImpl.getAutorizacionDeterminada(AutorizacionDAOImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy44.getAutorizacionDeterminada(Unknown Source)
    at es.iberia.tryp.services.impl.AdministracionServiceImpl.getAutorizacionDeterminada(AdministracionServiceImpl.java:233)
    at es.iberia.tryp.controllers.AdministracionController.getJSONAutorizacion(AdministracionController.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Haha, spanisch stack traces are funny to read. _columna definida de forma ambigua_ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED CHANGING THE JOIN:**

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_ESCALA",referencedColumnName="ID_ESCALA",insertable=false,updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="ANO",referencedColumnName="ANO",insertable=false,updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="MES",referencedColumnName="MES",insertable=false,updatable=false)
})
private PoaUpa poaUpa;
```

**FOR THIS JOIN:**

```
@OneToOne
  @JoinTable(name="TTR_POA_UPA",
    joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name="ANO", insertable=false, updatable=false),
      @JoinColumn(name="ID_ESCALA", insertable=false, updatable=false),
      @JoinColumn(name="MES", insertable=false, updatable=false)          
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name="ANO", insertable=false, updatable=false),
      @JoinColumn(name="ID_ESCALA", insertable=false, updatable=false),
      @JoinColumn(name="MES", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    }     
  )
private PoaUpa poaUpa;
```

**EDIT:** Show [Why changing the order of the joinColumn, hibernate return a correct or incorrect query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11342733/1474638) for more details